# FastBert TypeError :forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'masked_lm_labels'

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, transformer-model, sentence-transformers

I am following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@vitalshchutski/french-nlp-entamez-le-camembert-avec-les-librairies-fast-bert-et-transformers-14e65f84c148)  and I have an error in this step:

```
lm_learner.fit(epochs=30,
        lr=1e-4,
        validate=True,
        schedule_type="warmup_cosine",
        optimizer_type="adamw")
```

And this is how I implement the pretrainedmodel:

```
lm_learner = BertLMLearner.from_pretrained_model(
                        dataBunch=databunch_lm,
                        pretrained_path='camembert-base',
                        output_dir=MODEL_PATH,
                        metrics=[],
                        device=device_cuda,
                        logger=logger,
                        multi_gpu=False,
                        logging_steps=50,
                        fp16_opt_level="O2"
                        )
```

The exact error is :
[image]

I only found old answers and it doesn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.26.1/en/model_doc/bert#transformers.BertForMaskedLM) (last transformer stable version v4.26.1), BertForMaskedLM now has argument `labels` instead of `masked_lm_labels`.
So, you can try downgrading transformers under version <=3.0.0.